# How to upload a continuously updated folder to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, upload

I have a folder that is continuously updated with new files over time. I would like to sync this folder to upload this folder to my Google Drive. Since the folder contains up to 20.000 files when fully updated. The Google app Backup and Sync can not handle such task.

I would like to ask how to efficiently upload such folder to Google Drive?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "The Google app Backup and Sync can not handle such task." -- did you try that? What's your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RClone is an option for Windows and Linux that can sync local folders to cloud services:

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/rclone-rsync-alternative

Cheers.
G.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.